# Bootstrap div below div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a div containing 3 cells, and I want to place another div below it. But for some reason it appears above the wrapper div. I tried some things I found on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is one of the solutions which was supposed to work:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2" id="col1"> col1 </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2 " id="col2"> col2 </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2" id="col3"> col3 </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="below">
This should be below the wrapper div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#col1{
    background-color: lime;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#col2{

    background-color:  aqua;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#col3{
    background-color:  lightpink;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper{
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 100px;


}
#below{
    border: solid 2px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;   
    clear: both;

}
```

Comment: Is your first div wrapped in a row div? And why does #wrapper have top: 100px;?

Comment: I wanted to place the #wrapper div below the start of the page and then another div below #wrapper.

Comment: @CuriousGuy so change `top: 100px` to `margin-top: 100px` on `#wrapper`?

Comment: I pasted your code to this and it looks right to me. https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/462/

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Can you explain to me why margin-top worked and not top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is you are using `top: 100px` on your wrapper element.

[top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top) on MDN:

> ... for relatively positioned elements, the offset that the element is
>   moved below its position in the normal flow if it wasn't positioned.

This means that when you move the `#wrapper`-element with `top` the `#below`-element stay in the same place as if you hadn't used `top`.

To fix the issue you can use `margin-top: 100px` instead, which won't change the normal flow of `#wrapper`.